# WSE Web Service Client SoapHeaderException

Tags: c#, soap-client, soapheader, wse

I am trying to build a client that interacts with a 3rd party SOAP Web Service.  This web service requires WSE Security.

I generated an old school .asmx web service from the WSDL of the Service I am trying to interact with.  The WSDL has no information in it about WSE Security.

Without the WSE Security I can connect fine.  However, I added WSE Security to my .asmx web service.

I added the following code to my client to add the WSE Username and Password

```
SoapContext requestContext = host.RequestSoapContext;
UsernameToken userToken = new UsernameToken("username", "password", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);
```

However, now when I call the ProcessMessage method I get the following exception which doesn't tell me very much:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Server unavailable, please try later
>
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>
> at Reynolds.Core.STARProxy.STARWebService.ProcessMessage(Payload& payload) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.Core\Web References\STARProxy\Reference.cs:line 105
>
> at Reynolds.Core.reynolds.SendGenericXMLRequest(XmlElement[] inputElements, String url, Guid[] guids) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.cs:line 191
>
> at Reynolds.Core.reynolds.SendGenericSingleXMLRequest(XmlElement inputXML, String url, Guid guid) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.cs:line 125
>
> at Reynolds.Core.reynolds.SendGenericSingleXMLRequest(XmlElement inputXML, String url) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.cs:line 120
>
> at Reynolds.Core.reynolds.SendGenericSingleXMLRequest(XmlElement inputXML) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.Core\Reynolds.cs:line 114
>
> at Reynolds.Testing.GUI.Form1.btnProcessMessage_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Reynolds.Testing\Reynolds.Testing.GUI\Form1.cs:line 33

The exception doesn't really give me much to work with here.  I tried doing various Google searches but wasn't able to get anywhere.

This is my first time using WSE so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: WSE is obsolete. It was replaced by WCF over six years ago. You should use WCF for new development instead.

Comment: I'm only building the client not the service.  The service requires WSE.  Can I build a WCF client that uses WSE?

Comment: In most cases, yes, you can build a WCF client for the WSE service. The problem might come in areas where WSE was non-standard (it shipped before the standards were completed). In this case, you might have to change the WCF configuration to match the non-standard.

Comment: BTW, I have found that "WSE" does _not_ look good on your resume...

Comment: I've never worked with WCF.  Any good tuturials on getting started with WSE and WCF?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info as a starting point. Don't ever use WSE unless you have no other choice at all.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The exception states `Server unavailable, please try later`.  This means either you have the wrong URL for the 3rd party web service or the 3rd party server is down.

Comment: When I click on "Get general help for this exception" it says "The exception is thrown when an XML Web Service method is called over SOAP and an exception occurs during processing of the SOAP header.  The service is available but is throwing an error somewhere/somehow.  When I take out the WSE security it works fine.